# Как работает данный код для шифрования слова шифром Цезаря?

Tags: c++

Откопал код шифра Цезаря на C++
Собственно, вот он:

```
string cipherOfCaesarEnglish(string word, int shift)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z') word[i] = 'a' + (word[i] - 'a' + (26 - shift)) % 26;
        else if (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z') word[i] = 'A' + (word[i] - 'A' + (26 - shift)) % 26;
    }

    return word;
}
```

Мне не очень понятно, как он работает, и это нужно исправить.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Как же я напишу код, который не понимаю?) @Санаев

Comment: Используется тот факт, что char=byte и циклический сдвиг на shift в пределах 26

Comment: @АндрейПоляков тогда может программирование бросить? алгоритм цезаря очень простой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
```

если  символ `word[i]` является какой то буквой из последовательности от `а` по `z`, т.е. является маленькой буквой из альфавита, то присваиваем значение:

символу `'a'`можем прибавить цифру не больше чем `25`, чтобы  не выходить за пределы альфавита, поэтому:

```
 word[i] = 'a' + к % 26; // k%26 всегда меньше 26
```

где `к` равен `word[i] - 'a' + (26 - shift)`, т.е это дистанция между символом и первой буквой альфавита `+` дистанция между количеством букв в альфавите и заданным числом. Та же логика, если это большая буква...